# Compact convergence implies local uniform convergence

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, compactness, uniform-convergence

> Let $D\subseteq\mathbb C$ be open. Show that $(f_n)\stackrel{\text{comp}}\longrightarrow f$ implies $(f_n)\to f$ local uniform on D.

Notes:

1) A sequence $(f_n):D\to\mathbb C$ is said to converge compactly if $(f_n)\mid_V\to f$  local uniform for every compact subset $V\subseteq D$.

2) A sequence $(f_n):D\to\mathbb C$ is said to converge local uniform if for each point $z\in D$ there exists neighbourhood $V$ such that $(f_n\mid_V)\to f_V$ uniform.

*Proof*. Since $(f_n)\stackrel{\text{comp}}\longrightarrow f$ we get $(f_n)\mid_V\to f$ local uniform for each compact subset $V\subseteq D$. Now arbitrarily choose $z\in D$. Since $D$ is open, there is an open disk $K_\epsilon(z)\subset D$. Since $V:=\overline{K_{\epsilon/2}(z)}\subset D$ is compact, $(f_n)_V\to f_V$ must be local uniform.

Question: Is my proof correct?

Comment: And your question is... ?

Comment: Whether my proof is correct. I've edited it.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.