# Reference Request: Local Uniform Convergence and Compact-Convergence are Equivalent

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, reference-request

Let $X$ be a locally-compact, metric space and $Y$ be a complete metric space.  It is easy to show that if $f_n$ converges compactly to $f$ in $C(X,Y)$ then it converges locally uniformly (see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2324845/compact-convergence-implies-local-uniform-convergence)) and if a sequence converges locally then it must converge compactly.

I'm looking for a reference showing the equivalence between these two notions...

Comment: Just apply the definition of local uniform convergence and then apply definition of compactness. you can do this yourself.

Comment: Oh I know how to prove it.  Its a 1 line proof.  However, I need a reference since the journal I'm submitting to has a very small page limit.

Comment: Just use the phrase "it's easy to see that.." and don't give a reference. Completeness of $Y$ seems irrelevant.

Comment: True, but I really don't like saying those things incase one of my readers (esp. referees) isn't familiar with this type of analysis (then they'd feel bad).

Comment: "Making use of the standard fact that ... "